# Laravel CORS:: PreflightMissingAllowedOriginHeader

Tags: php, laravel, cors

I recently got into learning Laravel. Currently having a CORS related issue which has been driving me nuts.

I followed this installation guide for the [Fruitcake cors package](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)

My cors.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
| or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
| in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
|
| To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
|
*/

'paths' => [],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => false,

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,
```

My kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ForceJsonResponse::class,
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Base\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Base\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Base\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Base\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        // \App\Http\Base\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Base\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Base\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

Laravel is run on: http://127.0.0.1:8000 and my frontend on http://localhost:8080/

Not sure if this is an issue.

/* EDIT */

Using a wildcard for `paths` did seem to solve the CORS issue on the `/playlist/{id}` URL. It does not work for URL's like `/playlist/{id}/refresh` ..

Answer (score 0):

Well you have it applying to no paths:

```
'paths' => [],
```

so probably add in the paths they should be able to access

```
'paths' => ['api/*'], // or whatever
```

Comment: Thanks, this partially fixed the issue. I did use `'paths' => ['*']` instead because the `['api/*']` did not work. I now have paths like `/playlists/1` being resolved, but paths like `/playlists/1/sync` still giving the CORS error ..